# Retrieve records/values from output of sql query in Google script after JSON parsing

Tags: sql, parsing, google-apps-script

I used this code I found on stack overflow

```
function method3()
{
var spreadsheetID = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
var queryColumnLetterStart = 'A';
var queryColumnLetterEnd = 'B';
var queryColumnLetterSearch = 'B';
var query = 8;
    // SQL like query
    myQuery = "SELECT * WHERE " + queryColumnLetterSearch + " = '" + query + "'";

    // the query URL
    // don't provide last row in range selection
    var qvizURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetID + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&headers=1&sheet=' + sheetName + '&range=' + queryColumnLetterStart + ":" + queryColumnLetterEnd + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(myQuery);
    Logger.log('qvizURL: '+qvizURL);

    // fetch the data
    var ret = UrlFetchApp.fetch(qvizURL, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getContentText();
    Logger.log(ret);

    var obj1 = JSON.parse(ret.replace("/*O_o*/", "").replace("google.visualization.Query.setResponse(", "").slice(0, -2));
    Logger.log('obj1:');
    Logger.log(obj1);

/* 2021-02-16 19:10CET - I added the code below that heads towards a solution - see output */
    var obj2 = obj1.table;
    Logger.log('obj2:');
    Logger.log(obj2);
    var obj3 = obj1.table.rows;
    Logger.log('obj3:');
    Logger.log(obj3);


}
```

Output after update:

```
19:12:17    Informatie  qvizURL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*********/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&headers=1&sheet=Form Responses 1&range=A:B&tq=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20B%20%3D%20'8'
19:12:17    Informatie  ret: /*O_o*/
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"326840072","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Timestamp","type":"datetime","pattern":"M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss"},{"id":"B","label":"Klant ID","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12)","f":"2/9/2021 22:22:12"},{"v":"8"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)","f":"2/9/2021 23:39:46"},{"v":"8"}]}],"parsedNumHeaders":1}});
19:12:17    Informatie  obj1:
19:12:17    Informatie  {table={parsedNumHeaders=1.0, cols=[{id=A, pattern=M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss, label=Timestamp, type=datetime}, {type=string, id=B, label=Klant ID}], rows=[{c=[{v=Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12), f=2/9/2021 22:22:12}, {v=8}]}, {c=[{f=2/9/2021 23:39:46, v=Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)}, {v=8}]}]}, version=0.6, sig=326840072, status=ok, reqId=0}
19:12:17    Informatie  obj2:
19:12:17    Informatie  {cols=[{label=Timestamp, pattern=M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss, type=datetime, id=A}, {label=Klant ID, id=B, type=string}], rows=[{c=[{f=2/9/2021 22:22:12, v=Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12)}, {v=8}]}, {c=[{f=2/9/2021 23:39:46, v=Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)}, {v=8}]}], parsedNumHeaders=1.0}
19:12:17    Informatie  obj3:
19:12:17    Informatie  [{c=[{v=Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12), f=2/9/2021 22:22:12}, {v=8}]}, {c=[{f=2/9/2021 23:39:46, v=Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)}, {v=8}]}]
```

I guess I should be able to retrieve my records/value from obj2. Tried several ways like obj2[0][0] or obj[0]['Timestamp'], but doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm.. do I somehow need to iterate through the object and do a push??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expanded structure of your `obj2`

```json
{
    cols=[
            {
                label=Timestamp,
                pattern=M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss,
                type=datetime,
                id=A
                
            },
            {
                label=Klant ID,
                id=B,
                type=string
                
            }
        ],
    rows=[
        {
            c=[
                {
                    f=2/9/2021 22:22:12,
                    v=Date(2021,1,9,22,22,12)
                    
                },
                {
                    v=8
                }
            ]
            
        },
        {
            c=[
                {
                    f=2/9/2021 23:39:46,
                    v=Date(2021,1,9,23,39,45)
                    
                },
                {
                    v=8
                    
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    parsedNumHeaders=1.0
}
```

There seem to be two time stamps, say you wanted the first one

```
obj2.rows[0].c[0].f
```

If its an object `{}` you can use both dot `.` and square bracket `[]` notation. If the key had a space in it, eg. `co ls` then it would need to be in square brackets `["co ls"]`.

For arrays `[1,2,3]` you can only use square brackets and index numbers, starting at 0.

For example, `rows` is a key of the main `obj2`, but the *value* of `rows` is an array. Then within the array are more objects. That is why you need to switch between different methods.